# python np.genfromtxt iterate files

Tags: python

I trying to write a python script to read data from two files and then plot some of the columns. The two files have the same format (9 cols, 100 rows). I am trying to do that in a "for" loop, for the sake of keeping the code more compact (e.g imagine I had 30 files). But my code fails to work with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./plot-test.py", line 19, in <module>
    np.genfromtxt(('fil'+str(i)), unpack = True, skip_header = 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1241, in genfromtxt
    fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 145, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 479, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
IOError: fil1 not found.
```

So here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fil1 ='/home/aya/Arietids/test-GR/back-2h.dat' 
fil2 ='/home/aya/Arietids/test-GR/back-gr-2h.dat'

fig = plt.figure()

for i in xrange(1,2):
      t[i],JD[i],a[i],e[i],inc[i],lasc[i],aper[i],tru[i],nam[i] = \
      np.genfromtxt(('fil'+str(i)), unpack = True, skip_header = 1)

for i in xrange(2,2):
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(a[i-1] - a[i])

for i in xrange(2,2):
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(e[i-1] - e[i])

plt.xlabel("Time, 0 = present") 
plt.ylabel("$\Delta$ e")

plt.savefig('ae.eps')
```

Any ideas why python can't find "fil1", or why in general the code breaks?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`"fil"+str(i)` is a string not the variable `fil1`.  So you are trying to open  file called `"fil1"`

Also a range does not include the upper bound so even if it worked you would not be opening both files either.

Put `fil1` and `fil2` in a list:

```
l  = [fil1, fil2]
for i, f in enumerate(l,1): # now i starts at 1
```

Comment: any idea how to tell python that "fil1" is a variable name?

Comment: @user3578925, I added to my answer, just put them in a list